# How to go about reformatting my code to use an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I basically need to make an array and put it in the private member section, and have it work the random number generator. Im not even sure if my teacher is asking for an array to hold the 1000 values, or if I need to make an array for each variable (zero, one, ....). The rubric states to use the private member array to hold the count of values returned from calls to the random generator.

3 hours of youtube videos.

``````````````
class Gen
{
private:

    int Numbergenerated;

public:
    Gen();
    void set_Numbergenerated(int);
    int get_Numbergenerated();
    void gener();
    void display(int zero, int one, int two, int three, int four, int five, int six, int seven, int eight, int nine);
};


Gen::Gen()....

void Gen::set_Numbergenerated(int n)...

int Gen::get_Numbergenerated()...

void Gen::gener()
{
    int result_of_gener;

    result_of_gener = rand() % 10;                  

    set_Numbergenerated(result_of_gener);
}

void display....

int main()
{
Gen g;
    unsigned seed;
    int zero = 0, one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0, five = 0, six = 0, seven = 0, eight = 0, nine = 0, count, num;
    seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);                

    cout << "Press Enter key to begin generating numbers" << endl;
    cin.get();

    for (count = 0; count <= 1000; count++) 
    {
        g.gener();
        num = g.get_Numbergenerated();

        cout << "Generation " << "+" << count << ":\t" << "Number generated: " << num << endl;     

        switch (num)
        {
        case 0: zero++;
            break;.....

g.display(zero, one, two, three,four,five, six, seven, eight, nine);

`````````````

*******spots with ...... placed to save space, probably unimportant parts.
``````````````

Comment: It sounds like some more clarification on what is required for the implementation would be helpful here.

Comment: my understanding is the the array has to create 1000 elements, then it has to be assigned randomly generated numbers, then it needs to count the number of times a zero, one, two, etc appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fill the array with 1000 elements, you can use the [count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/) function to determine the number of occurrences of a specific value in the array. Here is how.

So, assuming you are using C++ [arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), we can declare the array in the private section of your class:

```
// An array of ints, with 1000 elements.
std::array<int,1000> randomNumberArray;
```

We can assume your `set_Numbergenerated` function adds a new random number to the array, so, in `main()`, we can generate and insert 1000 random numbers:

```
/** Generate 1000 random numbers to fill the array. */
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    g.gener();
}
```

Since our array is a private member, and not directly accessible from `main`, we can add a public member function to `Gen` to access the array for us. We can also tell this method to `count` the number of occurrences of a specific value in the array (a great C++ [algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)):

```
// Return the number of occurrences of 'val' in the array.
int Gen::get_Occurrences(int val) {
    return std::count(this->randomNumberArray.begin(), this->randomNumberArray.end(), val);
}
```

Finally, we can call this method for each number of interest (0 through 9), and give the result of each to the `display` method call in `main`:

```
g.display(g.get_Occurrences(0), g.get_Occurrences(1), g.get_Occurrences(2), 
        g.get_Occurrences(3), g.get_Occurrences(4), g.get_Occurrences(5), 
        g.get_Occurrences(6), g.get_Occurrences(7), g.get_Occurrences(8), g.get_Occurrences(9));
```

These and a few other minor edits produced the output:

```
Press Enter key to begin generating numbers

Occurrences of each number [0 - 9]: 95 87 106 112 107 96 109 104 100 84
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a little ambiguous.  I tried to keep as much of your code as I could, but I may have removed parts that were required to be in the assignment.

The numberGenerated is a confusing variable.  It seems that the more important thing you are trying to track is the frequencies of each digit.  To do this, I created a 10 element vector which is zeroed by the constructor.

Then, as each number is stored into the object, the corresponding bucket in the array is incremented.

Note that the constructor also calls the seed function for the random number generator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Gen {
private:

    int Numbergenerated;
    unsigned seed;
    std::vector<int> frequencies;

public:
    Gen();
    void set_Numbergenerated(int);
    int get_Numbergenerated();
    void generate_random_number();
    void display();
};

Gen::Gen()
{
  seed = time(0);
  srand(seed);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    frequencies
        .push_back(0);// create and zero 10 buckets in our frequencies vector
  }
}

void Gen::set_Numbergenerated(int n)
{
  Numbergenerated = n;
  frequencies[n] = frequencies[n] + 1;
}

int Gen::get_Numbergenerated()
{
  return Numbergenerated;
}

void Gen::generate_random_number()
{
  int result_of_generate;
  result_of_generate = rand() % 10;
  set_Numbergenerated(result_of_generate);
}

void Gen::display(){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << i << "'s: " << frequencies[i] << " ";
    sum += frequencies[i];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Total generated: " << sum << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Gen g;

  std::cout << "Press Enter key to begin generating numbers" << std::endl;
//  std::cin.get();

  for (int count = 0; count < 1000; count++) {
    g.generate_random_number();
    int num = g.get_Numbergenerated();

    std::cout << "Generation " << "+" << count << ":\t" << "Number generated: "
              << num << std::endl;
  }
  g.display();
}
```